# I woud like to know what type of effect has been used in the UI design of the website?

Tags: website-design, animation, trend, parallax

What type of effect has been used in the home page of this website as the image moves with the cursor .
https://www.niarratravel.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean what's the effect called, I'd say "parallax effect" is what you're looking for ☺

Answer (score 0):

in development is not an "effect" but a function used to accomplish such effects. This effect is done with GSAP a Javascript library, and you can find an example here for the developer to use. Hope iot helps [GSAP TILT CANVAS](https://codepen.io/emanuelbaran/pen/PPOdmw)